# How do you calculate the cumulative median in time series data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

"month" indicates the month in which the product was sold.
"sold time" shows how many minutes after the store opened product was sold.

| product | month | sold time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | Jan | 20.0 |
| A1 | Jan | 10.0 |
| A1 | Feb | 30.0 |
| A2 | Jan | 10.0 |
| A2 | Jan | 20.0 |
| A2 | Jan | 30.0 |
| A2 | Feb | NaN |
| A2 | Mar | 10.0 |

I would like to calculate the cumulative median of "sold time", grouped by product and month like below table.

| product | month | median sold time |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | Jan | 15.0 |  |
| A1 | Feb | 20.0 |  |
| A2 | Jan | 20.0 |  |
| A2 | Feb | 20.0 |  |
| A2 | Mar | 15.0 |  |

For median "sold time" of A2 in February, I want to get the median value among the sales of A2 in January and February.
For median "sold time" of A2 in March, I want to get the median value among the sales of A2 in January, February, and March.

### My program

I came up with the following program, but it didn't give me the results I expected.

```py
df['median sold time'] = df.groupby(['product', 'month'])['sold time'].expanding().median().reset_index()
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: I've tried random things and this seems to work. `print(df.groupby(['product','month']).median().reset_index())` . However try to replace Nan with 0 using `df['col_name'].replace(np.nan,0)` for consistency. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. First we create our df, here for completeness:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
"""
product,month,sold time
A1,Jan,20.0
A1,Jan,10.0
A1,Feb,30.0
A2,Jan,10.0
A2,Jan,20.0
A2,Jan,30.0
A2,Feb,NaN 
A2,Mar,10.0
"""))
df['sold time'] = df['sold time'].astype(float)
```

Next we create a rolling series of median (I call it `rm` for  short) with a large `window` (100, you may want to use more -- this will basically capture all observations 'to date') but a small `min_periods` so we calculate all partial results:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['product']).apply(lambda d: d.assign(rm = d['sold time'].rolling(window = 100, min_periods = 1).median())).reset_index(drop = True)
df2
```

this produces

```
    product    month      sold time    rm
--  ---------  -------  -----------  ----
 0  A1         Jan               20    20
 1  A1         Jan               10    15
 2  A1         Feb               30    20
 3  A2         Jan               10    10
 4  A2         Jan               20    15
 5  A2         Jan               30    20
 6  A2         Feb              nan    20
 7  A2         Mar               10    15
```

So we are almost there, but need to choose the last observation for each product/month:

```
df2.groupby(['product','month']).last()
```

final output

```
            sold time   rm
product month       
A1      Feb 30.0        20.0
        Jan 10.0        15.0
A2      Feb NaN         20.0
        Jan 30.0        20.0
        Mar 10.0        15.0
```

note the above assumes that months were already sorted, and I did not reset the index at the end, in case you want to

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
df['sold time'] = df['sold time'].astype(float)
df = df.groupby(['product','month'])['sold time'].median().reset_index()
```

Make sure to set your values in the `sold time` column as floats. If you want them as integers, simply change it to `astype(int)`.

This will give you the following output:

```
  product month  sold time
0      A1   Feb       30.0
1      A1   Jan       15.0
2      A2   Feb        NaN
3      A2   Jan       20.0
4      A2   Mar       10.0
```

If you then want to order the month column for each product, you can do the following, where you're converting the month to it's number form, sorting the `product` and `month` column in ascending order and then converting the month number back to month name:

```
import calendar
df["month"] = pd.to_datetime(df.month, format='%b', errors='coerce').dt.month
df = df.sort_values(['product', 'month'], ascending=[True, True]).reset_index()
df['month'] = df['month'].apply(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[x])
```

Which gives the following output:

```
  product month  sold time
0      A1   Jan       15.0
1      A1   Feb       30.0
2      A2   Jan       20.0
3      A2   Feb        NaN
4      A2   Mar       10.0
```

Finally, if you want to replace the `NaN` with a 0, you can do the following:

```
import numpy as np
df['sold time'] = df['sold time'].replace(np.nan, 0.0)
```

which gives the following output:

```
  product month  sold time
0      A1   Jan       15.0
1      A1   Feb       30.0
2      A2   Jan       20.0
3      A2   Feb        0.0
4      A2   Mar       10.0
```